# What is the purpose passing user_id in event logging and can we filter the user specific data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to display the **screen view count** and **average spending time** on each screen for a **particular user** in Firebase analytics dashboard.
for example if i select the particular user it should display screen_view_count and avg time of each screen in Firebase Analytics Dashboard.

i tried this way. but it not realistic if the user count is huge.
Expected:

> if i select the particular user it should display screen_view_count and avg time of each screen in Firebase Analytics Dashboard.